# Spring Integration - Difference from channel and int:channel

Tags: spring-integration

I'm studing by few days Spring Integration and in some example i've noticed the use of `channel` and `int:channel`.

What is the difference ?

In the same way, there are other keywords: someone start with `int:` and other (with the same name) are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just depends on how you configure the namespaces at the top of the XML file, and specifically the default `xmlns`. In the first case, the integration schema is the default, in the second, something else is, usually `beans`...

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    ...
```

In this case, integration is the default `xmlns` and you would use

```
<channel ...
```

and

```
<beans:bean ...
```

here...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    ...
```

`beans` is the default `xmlns` and you would use

```
<int:channel...
```

and

```
<bean ....
```

So, it's simply a matter of personal choice.

Comment: Many thanks,  I thought it was so but I wanted to have it confirmed :)